# Replacing all occurrences of a substring with ascending numbers

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to figure out a way to replace alle occurrences of a substring with ascending numbers.

If we say the substring, I wanted to replace is `"foo"` and the whole string is `"bar foo foo bar bar foo bar"`, the final string would be `"bar 0 1 bar bar 2 bar"`.

I have scoured Google for a solution to this, but found no answers. The closest I could find was replacing all occurrences of a substring with a specific string.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with `Regex.Replace` and an inline `MatchEvaluator` that returns and post-increments a counter:

```
var str = "bar foo foo bar bar foo bar";
var r = new Regex("foo");
var c = 0;
var replacedString = r.Replace(str, m => (c++).ToString());
    // = bar 0 1 bar bar 2 bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
        string input = "bar foo foo bar bar foo bar";
        string output = string.Empty;

        var words = input.Split(' ');
        int numberOfOccurencies = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
        {

            if (words[i] == "foo")
            {
                words[i] = numberOfOccurencies.ToString();
                numberOfOccurencies++;
            }
        }
        output = string.Join(" ", words);
```

I think it is easier to understand.